# Enlarge single character in SpannableString will have affect on line spacing (In Marshmallow only)

Tags: android

I have the following method, which enlarge the first character in `TextView`.

```
private void makeFirstLetterBig(TextView textView, String title) {
    final SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(title);
    int position = 0;
    spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2.0f), position, position + 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    //textView.setText(spannableString.toString());
    textView.setText(spannableString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

Here's the `TextView` being used.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="?attr/newsTitleTextViewSelector"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:text="TextView" />
```

Here's is the outcome before Marshmallow 6.

[image]

It looks pretty fine, as when the text content wraps to the 2nd line, the large first character doesn't affect 2nd line.

However, when running the same app in Marshmallow 6, I get the following outcome.

[image]

It seems that, the big character "I" is creating a large padding for the entire text content. This causes 2nd line (**with Amazon**) has a huge line spacing with 1st line.

May I know, how can I avoid such problem in marshmallow 6? I wish to have the same outcome as pre-marshmallow's.

p/s I filed a report at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191187 too.

### Update

On 9 December 2015, Google has fixed this issue and it will be released in Android 6.0.1 - https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191187

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** The issue is caused by a bug in the method `generate` of `StaticLayout`.

The bug is a little different from what I thought initially, it doesn't affect all the rows but only those after the enlarged character, as you can see from the screenshot:

[image]

In Marshmallow a `FontMetrics` cache was added to avoid recomputing, as explained by a comment in the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/text/StaticLayout.java#L694-L696):

```
// measurement has to be done before performing line breaking
// but we don't want to recompute fontmetrics or span ranges the
// second time, so we cache those and then use those stored values
```

Unfortunately the `fm.descent` value available in the cache is discarded if it is lower than the previous cached value, as you can see in the [snippet](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/core/java/android/text/StaticLayout.java#L792-L794):

```
for (int spanStart = paraStart, spanEnd; spanStart < paraEnd; spanStart = spanEnd) {
    // retrieve end of span
    spanEnd = spanEndCache[spanEndCacheIndex++];

    // retrieve cached metrics, order matches above
    fm.top = fmCache[fmCacheIndex * 4 + 0];
    fm.bottom = fmCache[fmCacheIndex * 4 + 1];
    fm.ascent = fmCache[fmCacheIndex * 4 + 2];
    fm.descent = fmCache[fmCacheIndex * 4 + 3];
    fmCacheIndex++;

    if (fm.top < fmTop) {
        fmTop = fm.top;
    }
    if (fm.ascent < fmAscent) {
        fmAscent = fm.ascent;
    }
    if (fm.descent > fmDescent) {
        fmDescent = fm.descent;
    }
    if (fm.bottom > fmBottom) {
        fmBottom = fm.bottom;
    }

    ....
```

Once the value reach the max, it will never decrease and this is why every following line has an increased line space.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for pointing out. Looks like we need to wait for Google to release next version of Android for this problem to fix? The code seems fairly complex to me. May I know how do you figure out, by able to correlate TextView.java with StaticLayout.java

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: if you use `ViewTreeObserver vto = textView.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
                Log.i("Log", layout.toString());
            }
        });` you will see `android.text.DynamicLayout` (when using `textView.setText(spannableString, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);`) or `android.text.StaticLayout` when `textView.setText(spannableString);`

Comment: @CheokYanCheng You're welcome. Unfortunately we can't fix the issue, we need to wait that Google fixes it in the next release of Android. The `StaticLayout` is correlated with `TextView` because [here](https://goo.gl/RLfssH) creates a new `DynamicLayout` when the text is a `Spannable` instance. Inside the `DynamicLayout` a `StaticLayout` is [created](https://goo.gl/W1c5pC) to generate the new layout. To better understand the issue I had to debug step by step the code until I found the problem. Starting from  [`draw` method](https://goo.gl/J5RcYu) of `TextLine` with a bottom-up approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in a position to try it at the moment, but this looks like something that you could work around with `setLineSpacing`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setLineSpacing(float,%20float)

Comment: Using `textView.setLineSpacing(0, 1.0f);` makes no difference.

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to; according to the docs, that combination of parameters will have no effect on the spacing. What I'm suggesting is that you might work around the issue by artificially bringing the lines closer together, with something like `setLineSpacing(0, 0.5f)`.

Comment: prefer not to go for such workaround, as it may break anytime soon, when Google fixes the problem.

Comment: That assumes Google *will* fix it. They may not, and even if they do, it probably won't be especially soon. You asked "how can I avoid such problem in marshmallow", and this workaround provides that.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an accepted answer, here is my solution which works fine in Marshmallow. it's just a rough implementation so you might improve it.

Knowing the *default fontmetrics* of your paragraph, it would be easy to detect whether it is a valid span changing the line height or it's just a bug by implementing `chooseHeight()` mehtod of `LineHeightSpan` which gives you access to each line metrics and range.

To use, just build your spannable and attach the `vLineHeightCheckSpan` markup to whole text or the range of your desire.

[Result Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gF6h.png)

```
public class vLineHeightCheckSpan implements LineHeightSpan
{
    private int mAscent, mDescent, mTop, mBottom;
    private Spanned mSpanned;

    public vLineHeightCheckSpan(Spanned spanned, TextPaint defaultTextPaint)
    {
        Paint.FontMetricsInt fm = defaultTextPaint.getFontMetricsInt();
        mAscent = fm.ascent;
        mDescent = fm.descent;
        mTop = fm.top;
        mBottom = fm.bottom;
        mSpanned = spanned;
    }


    @Override
    public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end, int spanstartv, int v, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm)
    {
        correctHeight(start, end, fm);
    }


    private void correctHeight(int start, int end, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm)
    {
        // check whether the line bound is different than default
        if(fm.top < mTop || fm.bottom > mBottom)
        {
            // get all spans which might affect the line height
            MetricAffectingSpan[] spans = mSpanned.getSpans(start, end, MetricAffectingSpan.class);

            // if there is none, set the line metrics to default
            if(spans.length == 0)
            {
                fm.top = mTop;
                fm.ascent = mAscent;
                fm.descent = mDescent;
                fm.bottom = mBottom;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

usage:

```
    // default layout textPaint
    TextPaint defaultTextPaint = new TextPaint(textPaint);

    // spannable
    Spannable styledText = new SpannableString(mText);

    final BackgroundColorSpan backgroundColor = new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW);
    final ForegroundColorSpan foregroundColorSpan = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
    final LeadingMarginSpan leadingMarginSpan = new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(leading);
    final AbsoluteSizeSpan absoluteSizeSpan = new AbsoluteSizeSpan(leadSize);


    styledText.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan, highLightStart, highLightEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    styledText.setSpan(backgroundColor, highLightStart, highLightEnd, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    styledText.setSpan(leadingMarginSpan, 0, mText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    styledText.setSpan(absoluteSizeSpan, 0, 1, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

    // add the line height check span
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == 23)
    {
        final vLineHeightCheckSpan checkHeightSpan = new vLineHeightCheckSpan(styledText, defaultTextPaint);
        styledText.setSpan(checkHeightSpan, 0, mText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }



    mLayout = new StaticLayout(styledText, defaultTextPaint, (int) initialRect.width(), Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 0, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there any way to get rid of that white space after FirstLine as shown in RESULT Image?

Comment: Android `StaticLayout` doesn't support full justification and it's only left/right/center alignment there. You need to use a 3rd party library like [Android TextJustify](https://github.com/bluejamesbond/TextJustify-Android).