# LineHeightSpan in Android M and lower versions

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, spannablestringbuilder

I wanna add multiple span to a textview with configurable line space. I use LineHeightSpan class defined in android. But it seems it behave differently in Android M and lower versions
Here the result in lower version of Android

[image]

and this is how it looks like in Android M
[image]

Here is how I implemented in code:
This is my implementation of LineHeightSpan:

```
public class VerticalMarginSpan implements LineHeightSpan {

    private final int value;

    public VerticalMarginSpan(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end, int spanstartv, int v,
                         Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
        fm.ascent -= value / 2;
        fm.descent += (value / 2);
    }
}
```

And how I use it:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder(tempStr);
    builder.setSpan(
            new VerticalMarginSpan(lineSpace),
            0,
            tempStr.length(),
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    txt.setText(builder);
```

How I can fix the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are having `Marshmallow v6.0` i afraid you can not do anything in this case as it's bug reported [Here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191187). You either have to upgrade your device to `v6.0.1` as it has been fixed in that version Or conditionally remove your logic from Marshmallow 6.0

**EDIT :** for more reference [check this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33252090/1185737)

Comment: I solve this problem in Android M by adding font spacing to textview instead of applying LineHeightSpan. You saved my time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I find that. This sample can help to provide your solution with vertical centered text.

```
public class VerticalLineSpacing implements LineHeightSpan {
  private int lineHeight;
  public VerticalLineSpacing (lineHeight) {
    this.lineHeight = lineHeight * 2;
  }
  @Override
  public void chooseHeight(CharSequence text, int start, int end, int spanstartv, int v, Paint.FontMetricsInt fm) {
    int halfLeading = (lineHeight - (fm.descent - fm.ascent)) / 2;
    fm.top -= halfLeading;
    fm.bottom += halfLeading;
    fm.ascent -= halfLeading;
    fm.descent += halfLeading;
  }
}
```